# want the loop to show result one by one on each iteration

Tags: php, caching, rss

Home page of my site is loading too slow. After examining my site I found that a 'for' loop which I used to retrieve data dynamically from an rss feed is making the problem.

The site takes 6-8sec for initial loading.
The loop which takes each item from the feed and echo the result in desired format. But only shows the site after the completion of the loop iteration with the whole result.

I want a solution for this
say for example

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){

echo $i;
}
```

I want the page load with result as '0' then successively shows 1,2,3...9

please suggest a method to solve this issue. Please if I get an example with your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speed problem is not in the loop, it's in loading the RSS xml file.  The best option would be to read from a local cache, and setup a cron job/daemon to update the cache regularly.

To do this, create an XML file on the system, and instead of reading from the remote file, read from your XML file.  To make a cron job to update the cache, write a script that reads from the remote file, and writes to the local XML file.  To make the cron job run, see here:

http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/introducing-cron

Comment: how should I maintain a local cache and do the cron job from there. can you please explain

Comment: the hosting server have to support the cronjob feature for this to work.  right??

Comment: Yes.  If it's a shared host, you'll have to use another method called "the poor man's cron".

Comment: I found the cronjob in my server. But this is a simple one. I cant run a cronjob from command, Instead I can schedule the cronjob for my domain by selecting the time/day and the file to use for that cronjob, so that it trigger file at the scheduled time. The php code in that file will do the rest. But dont know how to make the script to pull rss feed from a remote url to my server with that. Do you have an idea/script for this to work

Comment: @Rahul TS: use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file-get-contents) to call the remote file, and then use [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/file-put-contents) (assuming you're on 5.3+) to write it to your local file.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to do this only in PHP.  You will need to set up the page so that everything is loaded and then use Javascript to pull the RSS feed into the page as it is loaded.

Comment: please can you let me an example